# When root, source another user's ~/.bashrc and get all environment variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sudo, environment-variables

I'm trying to develop a small system app that is run as root.
In this app, I would like to list all environment variables of the default user (not the `$USER`, but the user who calls runs the app as root, i.e. `$SUDO_USER`). Since the app runs not from a terminal and relies on a process opened by C in Qt environment, I would like to first prepare the environment, then get the environment variables in this subprocess.

What I'm trying to accomplish is equivalent to:

- Change from root to user
- source ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile etc.
- printenv [and get it after the script]
- Change to root again

There are some workarounds that I discovered and read online, but I found those workarounds (for running a command as another user) not helpful in what I'm trying to achieve.

I need a one-liner for the aforementioned task. What I have right now is given below (run as root):

```
sudo -i -u user sh -c '. /home/user/.bashrc && printenv > /tmp/user.env'
```

Although I'm able to see a few environment variables with this, I cant see the custom exported ones from /home/user/.bashrc

Any guidance is appreciated,

In case of missing information, please let me know.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your command and it seems to me that it's working just find.

```
sudo -i -u user1 sh -c 'source ~/.bashrc && printenv > /tmp/user.env'
```

I've used the [source](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html) command instead of `.`

With `~/.bashrc` containing:

```
[ws] root ~ >cat /home/user1/.bashrc 
# .bashrc
...
export TESTENV="test"
...
```

execute your command and display the content of `/tmp/user.env`:

```
[ws] root ~ >sudo -i -u user1 sh -c 'source ~/.bashrc && printenv > /tmp/user.env'

[ws] root ~ >cat /tmp/user.env 
...
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=user1
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash -c sh -c source\ ~/.bashrc\ &&\ printenv\ >\ 
...
TESTENV=test
...
[ws] root ~ >
```

Comment: That is really weird. That is exactly what I tried right now and it doesnt seem to work for me. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I don't get the variables in ~/.bashrc

Comment: I've tested it on CentOS.

Comment: If you `su - user1` and then `printenv`, do you see the env variables you want?

Comment: Yes, that works. If I ```printenv``` when I'm user. Then, it works.

Comment: But I need a one-liner that involves environment refresh

Comment: Yes, I get that but I wanted to be sure ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72826/discussion-between-kevin-lemaire-and-mozcelikors).